# Android apps on phones and tablets

Tags: android

I'm developing a project that needs to work on both tabs and smart phones with different screen sizes, but I'm not sure how to achieve that. Should I use different codes for different devices or I need to deal with the drawable folder with h/l/m/xhdpi or there is another way to do that ?

Comment: Layout/Drawable folders make life easier compared to adapting via code,so use those.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html and http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html and http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html